# Can a Directory alone load specific query on a page?

Tags: php, url, redirect, directory

On websites such as facebook and many others you see URLs such as www.facebook.com/username. How does a URL such as this actually load the users information from a MySQL database? and what is the actual file it is displaying on? I would assume there's not really a folder for each user that it is referring to. If my question doesn't make sense can you at least point me in the right direction to set something like this up through PHP?

Again, I want example.com/username to load my users profile. How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using apache's .htaccess file to manage a RewriteEngine, all of your pages can be funneled through an index.php file. After confirming that the requested page is not actually a page that you've intended to be a default part of your web page, you can fall back on the code below, to discover a user account. If a user account is not discovered, then the likelihood is that the page being accessed is simply a 404, which you could then redirect to as a catch-all scenario

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(xml|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|php|txt|html|otf)$ index.php
```

php logic to run after confirming the requested page, isn't something like a contact-us page, or any typical web page an end user would be attempting to access.

```
if(preg_match("/^\/(?P<username>[^\/]*)/", $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'], $matches)) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($matches['username']) . "'");

    if($user_record = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "DO WHATEVER YOUR HEART CONTENTS HERE :)";
    } else {
        header("Location: error-404.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: This was very useful. Thank you. I It seems there is a lot that is possible using .htaccess. I will definitely need to spend more time learning about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is all loaded dynamically via the database. For example, my Facebook name is "benroux". In facebook's user table, there is going to be a unique column called, lets say, nickname. When I visit Facebook, they are parsing the path info and essentially calling a query in the form:

```
select * from user where nickname = "{$nickName}"
```

Now, this is an over simplified example, but I hope it gives you an idea of what is going on here. The key is that there are 2 types of url vars, the `facebook.com/pagename.php?id=blah` and the restful style path info vars `facebook.com/pagename/var1/var2/`

If you are looking to have `example.com/benroux` load my user page, you need to make your index.php (I'll use PHP) load the path info ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php ) and then query the database as I have described above.

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't fully solve it for me, but definitely sets me on the correct path. I will look more into the pathinfo function and see if I can pull this off. I already have my database setup with users and profile pages etc. I just want to be able to direct them to there profiles with a more user friendly URL.

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

you will get that parameters. Then you just need to split them.
Something like

```
$directory = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].split('/')[1];
```

So, put `$directory` into query